# Specify the windows folder path in VBScript

Tags: email, vbscript, email-attachments, cdo.message

I have a vbscript ,which sends the folder contents as attachments to my email but the problem is i am unable to specify the path of windows folder because the windows path is different for different computers.

In my code following works

`Const PATH = "C:\windows\Folder1\"`

but since path is different for different machines. i tried following but no success

`Const PATH = "%windows%\Folder1\"`

Here is the full vbscript code

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM


Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder
Dim oFile
Dim oFiles
Const PATH = "%windows%\Folder\" 'This method not working!!!!! 
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(PATH)
Set oFiles= oFolder.files
objMessage.Subject = "This is the email subject"
objMessage.From = "mailSender@MyMail.com"
objMessage.To = ""
objMessage.TextBody = "This is the body of the email. I’m fairly unoriginal"
For Each oFile in oFolder.files
objMessage.AddAttachment PATH & oFile.name
Next
'==This section will provide the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
```

when the  configuration information for the remote SMTP server the code works perfectly.

how will i specify the windows,programfiles,desktop(special folders) in this script??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
>>
C:\WINDOWS

>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
>>
C:\Documents and Settings\eh\Desktop
```

**UPDATE:**

sample usage:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Your problem in a nutshell
'Const PATH = "c:\windows\system"  ' fails on systems with %windir% <> c:\windows
'Const PATH = "%windir%\system"  ' fails with "Path not found" (FSO does not expand env vars)

Dim goWS   : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' PATH can't be a Const, because Consts can be initialized with literals only
' I use the prefix "cs" to indicate "constant string - keep your fingers off!"
Dim csPATH  : csPATH   = goWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\system")
Dim csDESKT : csDESKT  = goWS.SpecialFolders("desktop")
WScript.Echo "# of files in system folder:", goFS.GetFolder(csPATH).Files.Count
WScript.Echo "# of files in desktop:", goFS.GetFolder(csDESKT).Files.Count
```

output:

```
cscript specfolders.vbs
# of files in system folder: 27
# of files in desktop: 49
```

Comment: so what should my script look like. sorry i am a beginner at vb-script please show where your code needs to be put??

Comment: thanks for your reply.i appreciate your sample usage and you understood me but As i mentioned i am a beginner, i tried to fit your code in mine but i get error every time e.g "expected fso".please edit my code and mention it on your reply. Reminder: my script works fine to attach contents of folder to email but "windows,program files etc" path is obviously the problem since it changes for different pc.seriously it will solve my weeks of frustration!!! thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Due to windows security architecture its not a good practice to do as you are trying. I would start from SpecialDirectories Class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SpecialDirectories.aspx

Comment: what should my script look like. sorry i am a beginner at vb-script please show where your code needs to be put?? the directory can be any common folder found in all windows e.g program files,windows,desktop etc

Answer (score -1):

If your objective is to send email with attachment? I will use the following example :

```
Public Shared Function SendMail(strFrom As String, strTo As String, strSubject As String, strMsg As String) As Boolean
Try
    ' Create the mail message
    Dim objMailMsg As New MailMessage(strFrom, strTo)

    objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    objMailMsg.Subject = strSubject
    objMailMsg.Body = strMsg
    Dim at As New Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded/txt.doc"))
    objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(at)
    objMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High
    objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True

    'prepare to send mail via SMTP transport
    Dim objSMTPClient As New SmtpClient()
    objSMTPClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis
    objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg)
    Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

End Function

Or

If you want to use folder location to attach the file. Firstly I will not use c:\windows\folder1 as a location for files. As this folder contains all your/clients system files and you might run into security issues.

Insert the following code :
Your code

```
\\ Const PATH = "%windows%\Folder\" 'This method not working!!!!! 
\\ Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(PATH)
```

Use the following

```
string PATH = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
```

Returns the string "C:\Users\Owner\Documents".  here you can add new folder in above code. use concatenation like this & "\" & "Folder1"

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: You mean string PATH?. Its a pseudo code to help submitter understand the logic. in vb.net it will be PATH as String...

Comment: I mean your *VB.NET* code; the OT asked for *VBScript* advice.